# How to own a folder and use by 3 users

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ftp, users, chmod

3 users, 1 folder.
Users: vsftpd (FTP server), bobmarley (normal user), www-data (Apache user)

How to unite them and make so that each user can modify any of these user's data, without doing CHMOD 777?

Ex.:
bobmarley created a file 'settings.inc.php'
www-data tries to access the file, and succeeds.
vsftpd user accesses the file and can modify it, too.

Answer (score 4):

Create a group (`groupadd`)... `chgrp` of the directory to that new group... and then add each user to that group.  That's the easiest way.   You may also want to `chmod g+s` on the directory to make sure that new files are created with the same group as the parent directory.

tadaa!

Answer (score 2):

```
groupadd webapp
usermod -a -G webapp vsftpd (but I think it should be nobody)
usermod -a -G webapp bobmarley
usermod -a -G webapp www-data
chgrp -R webapp /path/to/folder
chmod -R g+w /path/to/folder
```

If you have existing data in this folder, you can set SGID for all sub-folders with:

```
find /path/to/folder -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod g+s /path/to/folder
```

Remember to set the `umask` for vsftpd, Apache and bobmarley to 002. With this config, all files created by any user will has 664 permission, owned by `webapp` group, and other users can modify.

Answer (score 1):

Put them all in a common group. `chgrp` the files to that group. `chmod` the files/dirs to 664/775.

Answer (score 0):

Group them. This is why there are groups in POSIX. Create a group `xyz` and put vsftpd, bobmarley and www-data into it.

And then assign the group to the folder/files with `chgrp`.